# opcache enabled, but why I don't see any difference

Tags: php, opcache

I have PHP 5.5 and opcache enabled

My phpInfo shows this : http://gyazo.com/97afb5a768f95e1ff2d35bb239a62afa

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.max_file_size=15M
opcache.max_wasted_percentage=5
opcache.use_cwd=1
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.save_comments=0
opcache.load_comments=0
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_file_override=1
```

But If I put it On or Off and restart apache I still don't see any difference in page loads...

••• I see "caches misses" ; what does this means ?
    And cache hits 0

I also installed different opcache gui panels and I see only 1 cached file.

••• I'm I missing something ?

Do I need to place a php opcache function in my php files ???

Thanks to help me.

Comment: `var_dump(opcache_get_status());` post the results ofthat

Comment: var_dump(opcache_get_status()); shows   [num_cached_scripts] => 85  [hits] => 0 [misses] => 85 .... What does hits and misses refers to ?

Comment: hit=cached file used, miss=original file served

Comment: can you post your full phpinfo , some types of php instances do not support opcache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally know what was the problem in my case...

My server was in suPHP and opcache was not really working even if php.ini says yes...

I switched to FastCGI and booom !!! opcache DOES make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

Opcache uses an SMA as its in-memory cache.  This only persists whist the process (or process tree) exists.  I suspect that you are using a CLI variant of PHP where the process only exists for one request. With the Apache and FastCGI variants, the cache does persist across multiple requests.